# When i set 404 using node js its not working when i reload my page

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, mean-stack

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dashboard/index.html');
});
```

In the above code 404 is redirecting to index.html, If the set 404.html & reload my page first time my content is load once i refresh my page its redirect to 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code once it may help you.

```
app.get('/something/*', function(req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/something/index.html');

});


app.get('*', function(req, res) {

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/something/404.html');

});

for rendering the html use your routing instead of something with* sign.
```